# Undefined method `time_series_path' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have this error when loading `index.html.rb`.

```
undefined method `time_series_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f6aac0d2a28>:0x007f6aac0d1358>
```

In routes.rb I have

```
namespace :viewer do
   resources :time_series
end
```

In the TimeSeriesController I have

```
class Viewer::TimeSeriesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @time_series = TimeSeries.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @time_series = TimeSeries.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
  end
end
```

In the index.html.rb I have

```
<h1>Listing of time series</h1>

<table  >
  <tr>
    <th>Kind</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <% @time_series.each do |t| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= t.kind %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', t %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
<%= will_paginate @time_series %>
```

The error occurs for the link_to 'Show' line.

Any ideas on how to resolve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a namespace, the namespace becomes part of the route name.

```
viewer_time_series_path
```

not

```
time_series_path
```

To double check, you can print out the list of all the routes

```
rake routes
```

and grep to immediately check the name

```
rake routes | grep time_series
```

In your code, you either pass the namespace as array in the `link_to` helper along with the object

```
<%= link_to 'Show', [:viewer, t] %>
```

or (I prefer this solution) you write the corresponding path explicitly.